# Geoserver returning Translator Error when I use PropertyIsLike

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I'm converting a WFS app from MapServer to GeoServer (2.1.4) and have hit a snag around PropertyIsLike. Whenever I include it in a getFeature's filter I get back a ServiceException as seen below.

This is the filter sent to getFeature:

```
<Filter xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/ogc' >
    <ogc:And>           
      <BBOX>
        <PropertyName>geom</PropertyName>
        <Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <coordinates>174.74029566015622,-37.005568168501505 175.0849917050781,-36.89582122701751</coordinates>
        </Box>
      </BBOX>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLike  wildcard="*" matchCase="false" singleChar="." escape="!">
        <ogc:PropertyName>locality</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>*reek*</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
  </ogc:And>
</Filter>
```

And this is the error

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
  <ServiceException>
    error:Translator error
    Translator error
    java.io.IOException
    null
    null
  </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

It works fine if I remove the PropertyIsLike, and it works if I change it to PropertyIsEqual, but I need a wild-card search. I've looked over and over the filter and I can't see a problem with it. Can someone see an error, or suggest another way to achieve a wild-card search on GeoServer?

*Update* Here is the requested full stack trace.

2012-07-16 15:55:41,953 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException:  error:Translator error
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.encode(GML2OutputFormat.java:286)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.write(GML2OutputFormat.java:295)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:141)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:751)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:394)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(ReverseProxyFilter.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Translator error
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:136)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:111)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.encode(GML2OutputFormat.java:276)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.iterator(ContentFeatureCollection.java:258)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.iterator(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:44)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:53)
    at org.geotools.gml.producer.FeatureTransformer$FeatureTranslator.encode(FeatureTransformer.java:513)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$XMLReaderSupport.parse(TransformerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:484)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$Task.run(TransformerBase.java:299)
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:132)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:576)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:484)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.iterator(ContentFeatureCollection.java:255)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQL.visit(FilterToSQL.java:450)
    at org.geotools.filter.LikeFilterImpl.accept(LikeFilterImpl.java:614)
    at org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQL.visit(FilterToSQL.java:544)
    at org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQL.visit(FilterToSQL.java:496)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.accept(AndImpl.java:64)
    at org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQL.encode(FilterToSQL.java:205)
    at org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQL.encodeToString(FilterToSQL.java:234)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.selectSQL(JDBCDataStore.java:2885)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:564)
    ... 84 more

Comment: Enable verbose exception reporting on the global page:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/server/globalsettings.html

and then update the question with the full stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was incredibly minor and poorly reported. Geoserver insists on "wildCard" but the filter I had used previously on Mapserver accepted "wildcard". It's clearly my fault for not using the right case, but would it be that hard to report that the required attribute was missing?

(I found the solution here http://osdir.com/ml/gis.geoserver.user/2005-09/msg00023.html)